# int pointer function seg fault with big numbers in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
int     *rrange(int start, int end);
```

I was asked, to write a function and allocate with malloc an array of integers, fill it with consecutive
values that begin at end and end at start (Including start and end !), then
return a pointer to the first value of the array. The functions works with small numbers, when tested with big numbers I get `seg fault`. And I think I got `seg fault` due to reaching the limit of `int`. How can I solve this issue?.

```
/*- With (1, 3) you will return an array containing 3, 2 and 1
- With (-1, 2) you will return an array containing 2, 1, 0 and -1.
- With (0, 0) you will return an array containing 0.
- With (0, -3) you will return an array containing -3, -2, -1 and 0.*/

#include <stdlib.h>

int *rrange(int start, int end)
{
    int *range;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
    if (end <= start)
    {
        while (end <= start)
            range[i++] = end++;
    }
    else
    {
        while (end >= start)
            range[i++] = end--;
    }
    return (range);
}

= Test 1 ===================================================
$> ./pw53y11cbachacu14eue5cab 
$> diff -U 3 user_output_test1 test1.output | cat -e

Diff OK :D
= Test 2 ===================================================
$> ./o1jrm4t3vqengizvj1tlwab4 "21" "2313" "12"
$> diff -U 3 user_output_test2 test2.output | cat -e

Diff OK :D
= Test 3 ===================================================
$> ./usl3i1tc1xv9tr1gs9n5x5vr "2147483647" "2147483640" "7"
$> diff -U 3 user_output_test3 test3.output | cat -e
--- user_output_test3   2016-06-08 16:26:16.000000000 +0200$
+++ test3.output    2016-06-08 16:26:16.000000000 +0200$
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@$
-0$
-0$
-0$
-0$
-0$
-0$
-0$
+2147483640$
+2147483641$
+2147483642$
+2147483643$
+2147483644$
+2147483645$
+2147483646$
$

Diff KO :(
Grade: 0

= Final grade: 0         ===============================================================
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int *));`, This will not allocate an `array` of int, it will allocate memory for a single int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segfault occurs due to wrong memory allocation

```
range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

this would allocate a memory of the size of an integer pointer. but to allocate memory for numbers you need to create required amount of memory for each number this way :

```
range = malloc(no_of_elements*sizeof(int));
```

> NOTE: use `n` as global variable so that you can know the size of
>   array even in function() where you print

and I've modified your function

```
int *rrange(int start, int end)
{
    int *range;
    int i;

    if(start>end)
        return rrange(end,start); //so that start is always <end

    n=end-start+1; // n globally declared 

    range=malloc(n*sizeof(int)); //casting is not required
    if(range==NULL)
    {// check if memory was successfully allocated if not exit
        printf("fail");
            exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++,start++)
    {
        range[i]=start;
    }

    return range;
}
```

you can now write your main as:

```
int main()
{
    int x,y,*r,i;
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    r=rrange(x,y);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d,",r[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, check this code http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/ak4BSE

Comment: it shows "No Output" there but on my linux it says, `seg fault`.

Comment: Have you tried after making the changes as I've done above? @TenTenPeter

Comment: Yes, thanks it works, but I have changed your code, I have to cast `malloc` , not use global variables and not use `for` loop, it's a school requirement.

Comment: Fine! Pleasure helping you :)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem comes from the `malloc`:

Instead of

```
range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

You should write:

```
range = malloc(nb_of_integer_in_range * sizeof (int));
```

Up to you to compute `nb_of_integer_in_range`, something like:

```
int nb_of_integer_in_range;
if (end > start)
{
    nb_of_integer_in_range = end - start + 1;
}
else ...
```

Comment: [reason for not casting the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: You can always use the size of the defererenced pointer itself in you `malloc` call to prevent any mixup, e.g. `range = malloc(nb_of_integer_in_range * sizeof *range);`

Comment: @purplepsycho Thanks, but I'm still getting `seg fault` http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/ak4BSE

Comment: @TenTenPeter aren't you missing a `+1` in linked code?

Comment: @purplepsycho no, I'm still getting `seg fault` even after adding `+1`

Comment: @TenTenPeter The problem you have in linked code is linked to `end<=start` comparison: As `start` is equal to the maximum integer representable in `int32_t`, the test `end <= start` will always be **true**: when `end` is equal to `start`, you increase `end` which becomes `0`...

Comment: @purplepsycho I was telling myself that the `<=` were going to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this worked with any range larger than 2. You're allocating 8B of storage (assuming you're running a 64b machine), or whatever is pointer size in general. 
What you want instead is a malloc expression that depends on the difference between `start` and `end` (giving you the array size) *and* `sizeof(int)` (giving you the array *element* size).

Unrelated note: make sure to free the storage when you stop using the array, otherwise your program will leak like a sieve.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `malloc` should be `number_of_integers * sizeof(int)`. The value of `number_of_integers` can for example be calculated as `abs(start-end)+1`, but I'd instead do the `malloc` inside the `if`-statement where the relation between start and end is known.

Comment: using the calculation: `abs(start-end)+1` and the values: start=-1, end=3)  the result would be abs(2)+1 yields 3 however that value yield should be 5.  Suggest: `abs( end - start ) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired function
3. properly handles error conditions
4. might not work if `start` is greater than `end` however, that was not part of the criteria

and now the code:

```
/*- With (1, 3) you will return an array containing 3, 2 and 1
- With (-1, 2) you will return an array containing 2, 1, 0 and -1.
- With (0, 0) you will return an array containing 0.
- With (0, -3) you will return an array containing -3, -2, -1 and 0.*/

#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h>  // perror()
#include <math.h>   // abs()

int *rrange(int start, int end)
{
    int *range = NULL;

    if( NULL == (range = malloc( sizeof(int) *((size_t)abs(end - start) +1) ) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for( int index = 0; index < abs(end-start)+1; index++ )
    {
        range[ index ] = start+index;
    }

    return (range);
} // end function: rrange
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use `<stdio.h>` , `<math.h>` and `for` loops. the only allowed function is `malloc`.

Comment: @TenTenPeter.  To generate all those numbers, your going to needs some kind of loop.  And `malloc()` is a function call while `for()` is a keyword in the language.   Rather than using `abs()`, you could make the calculation into a stack variable, then test, using `if()` to check if the result is negative, then if negative, multiply by -1.  I would expect that your instructor would never suggest using a `goto` statement, as such a statement (almost) always a bad idea and a sign of poor algorithm development.  Will your instructor let you use a `while()` statement?

Comment: @TenTenPeter. it is very poor programming practice to not check for error conditions returned from system functions.  and announcing such an error requires I/O which requires `stdio.h`